# avoid data type check in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have typeahead autosuggest field in my rails form for taking the name of person but in the model i have id for the person but the problem is when i create the person object and redirect to the same form its giving me an error undefined method `person_name' for #<*Worker:0x007fb97842f0c0*>

```
<%= form_for :worker, :url => {:action => :create_worker} do |f|  %>

    <%= f.text_field ("person_name"),:class => "typeahead form-control",style:"width:100%;",:placeholder=>"Enter name" , :data => {:provide => "typeahead"}%>

<%end%>
```

Any suggestion would be a great help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). 
- please add the *complete* error message to your question.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle thanks for suggestions have added proper error message now

Comment: On a side note - don't add a space between the name of a method and the parens. While it does not cause an error with single arguments `foo (a,b)` will cause a syntax error since the parens is treated as a single argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a field in the workers table called person_name? You need to use the same attribute name as defined in the schema e.g. if the attribute is `name`, you should use name. Also you probably want to use a symbol for the method and not a string

```
<%= f.text_field :name, :class => "typeahead form-control" %>
```

It might be worth reading the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Comment: @ margo thanks a lot the problems is solved now i was confused with text_field attribute and thought that it can be any string. Thanks